# Calling method of non-immediate relative class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Is it possible to call the base of a base method? I.E. a not an 'immediate' ancestor of a derived class?

```
public class a
{
    public virtual void test() { }
}

public class b : a
{
    public override void test()
    {
        //...
        base.test();
    }
}

public class c : b
{
    public override void test()
    {
        //...
        //possible to call test() in  class a, without calling it in class b? 
        //((a)base).test(); //doesnt work

    }
}
```

Comment: That's not possible and you don't want to do that anyway. Please explain what you are trying to achieve so we can suggest a good solution.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Was writing some code and the thought crossed my mind if it was possible

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not possible and goes against OOP principles. If you need to do that you probably designed your system wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Not with C#. C# only allows you to call methods on the immediate base class.

The CLR on the other hand allows it. You can do it with reflection, or by writing IL directly. I assume C++/CLI supports this too.

But I'd reconsider the design. Skipping an override smells of bad design and breaks the encapsulation of your base class.